# Adding multiple products to cart failing

Tags: cart, addtocart

Assuming I want to create a link for the customer to click on that automatically adds some items to cart and redirects them to the cart.

I created a controller that adds two items to cart, problem is, it's only adding the first item to cart, tried switching the order of the items and same problem.

Any ideas?

```
public function specialsAction(){
    $prod_one = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($prod_one_id);
    $prod_two = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($prod_two_id);

    $params_one = array(
        'product' => $prod_one->getId(),
        'qty' => 1
    );

    $params_two = array(
        'product' => $prod_two->getId(),
        'qty' => 1
    );
    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();

    // this item gets saved to cart, since its the first item i'm adding
    $cart->addProduct($prod_one, $params_one);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    // this item does NOT get added (unless I add it first to the cart)
    $cart->addProduct($prod_two, $params_two);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

**Answer**

Since the answer below is a bit ambiguous I'm pasting the solution below:

```
    $cart->addProduct($prod_one, $params_one);
    // REMOVE these two lines and place them only at the end of all the product additions
    //$cart->save();
    //Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);


    $cart->addProduct($prod_two, $params_two);

    // HERE is where we save
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
...
$params_one = array(
    'product_id' => $prod_one->getId(),
    //^__change to product id
    'qty' => 1
);

$params_two = array(
    'product_id' => $prod_two->getId(),
    //^__change to product id
    'qty' => 1
);

$cart->addProduct($prod_one, $params_one);
$cart->addProduct($prod_two, $params_two);

$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

or

```
// assuming this is a simple product without option
$qty = 1;
$cart->addProduct($prod_one_id, $qty);
$cart->addProduct($prod_two_id, $qty);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Read more [Add Products to cart Programmatically in Magento](http://mohitvrma.blogspot.com/2014/04/add-products-to-cart-programmatically.html)

See /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php

```
/**
 * Add product to current order quote
 * $product can be either product id or product model
 * $config can be either buyRequest config, or just qty
 *
 * @param   int|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param   float|array|Varien_Object $config
 * @return  Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create
 */
public function addProduct($product, $config = 1)
{
    if (!is_array($config) && !($config instanceof Varien_Object)) {
        $config = array('qty' => $config);
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! using just one `$cart->save();` and `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);` at the end helps, the whole change to `product_id` didn't seem to make any difference